# How to display a floating action button on long pressing a listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app that should contain a list on long pressing a list item the floating action button should be displayed on bottom of screen

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you list item with `GestureDetector` it has a property called `onLongPress` .You can keep a bool value set to false and onLongPress set the bool to true and show the floating action button.

#Edit1
declare a bool,

```
bool showFab = false;
```

your FAB

```
floatingActionButton: showFab ? FloatingActionButton(...) : SizedBox(),
```

Your listtile

```
GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: () {
      setState((){
showFab = true;
})
    },
    child: YourListWidget(),
  )
```